# python script to merge more than 200 very large csv very in just one

Tags: python, csv

I have been trying to merge several .csv files form different subfolders (all with the same name) into one. I tried with R but I got the result of not enough memory for carry the process (it should merge more than 20 million of rows). I am now working with a python script to try to get it (see below) it has many columns too so I don't need all of them but also I dont know if can choose which columns to add to the new csv:

```
import glob
import csv
import os

path= 'C:\\path\\to\\folder\\where\\all\\files\\are-allowated-in-subfolders'
result = glob.glob('*/certificates.csv')
#for i in result:
#full_path = "C:\\path\\to\\folder\\where\\all\\files\\are-allowated-in-subfolders\\" + result
#print(full_path)
os.chdir(path)
i=0
for root, directories, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(name)
        try:
            i += 1
            if i % 10000 == 0:
                #just to see the progress
                print(i)
                if name == 'certificates.csv':
                    creader = csv.reader(open(name))
                    cwriter = csv.writer(open('processed_' + name, 'w'))
                    for cline in creader:
                        new_line = [val for col, val in enumerate(cline)]
                        cwriter.writerow(new_line)

        except:
            print('problem with file: ' + name)
            pass
```

but it doesn't work, and neither return any error so at the moment I am completely stuck.

Comment: All are columns (i.e. headers of files) exactly same for all of your *.csv files?

Comment: You probably don't want to indent `if name == 'certificates.csv':` and everything below it

Comment: On first surface look, your indentation does no seem right. After printing the "progress message" your indentation should go back one level.

Comment: `cwriter = csv.writer(open('processed_' + name, 'w'))` will overwrite the same file over and over. You mihgt want to use `with open("processed_certificates.csv" ,"w") as allfiles: ...` and write to that. or use "a" to append to it.

Comment: @Daweo yes they have the same name of the columns and same position.

Comment: @MartinEvans  when don't indent this piece it jumps to the error. That why I though should be indented

Comment: @deponovo I tired but it jumps me to the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to keep a `merged.csv` file open whilst reading in each of the `certificates.csv` files. `glob.glob()` can be used to recursively find all suitable files:

```
import glob
import csv
import os

path = r'C:\path\to\folder\where\all\files\are-allowated-in-subfolders'
os.chdir(path)

with open('merged.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_merged:
    csv_merged = csv.writer(f_merged)
    
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*/certificates.csv'), recursive=True):
        print(filename)
        
        try:
            with open(filename) as f_csv:
                csv_merged.writerows(csv.reader(f_csv))
        except:
            print('problem with file: ', filename)
```

An `r` prefix can be added to your path to avoid needing to escape each backslash. Also `newline=''` should be added to the `open()` when using a `csv.writer()` to stop extra blank lines being written to your output file.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong, and you are overwriting the output file for each new input file.  Also, you are not using the `glob` result for anything.  If the files you want to read are all immediately in subdirectories of `path`, you can do away with the `os.walk()` call and do the `glob` after you `os.chdir()`.

```py
import glob
import csv
import os

# No real need to have a variable for this really
path = 'C:\\path\\to\\folder\\where\\all\\files\\are-allowated-in-subfolders'
os.chdir(path)
# Obviously, can't use input file name in output file name
# because there is only one output file for many input files
with open('processed.csv', 'w') as dest:
    cwriter = csv.writer(dest)
    for i, name in enumerate(glob.glob('*/certificates.csv'), 1):
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            #just to see the progress
            print(i)
        try:
            with open(name) as csvin:
                creader = csv.reader(csvin)
                for cline in creader:
                    # no need to enumerate fields
                    cwriter.writerow(cline)
        except:
            print('problem with file: ' + name)
```